# Replace <null> string in nsdictionary

Tags: ios, nsdictionary

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Iterating through NSDictionary for null value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8477789/iterating-through-nsdictionary-for-null-value)

I have a json like [image](http://mocku.ps/wz69f), **i want to replace all value  string to an empty string**. I see [that it is similar to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12213822/replace-occurance-of-nsnull-in-nested-nsdictionary) but all the value  have not changed.

Comment: Use **[NSNULL null]** replace null string

Comment: @Price: It is a NSDictionary, not a nsstring

Answer (score 2):

Your `"<null>"` is not a null! This is a NSString.
If you want null in your JSON you should have

```
"someKey": null
```

If you want to repleace it you should use [NSNull class](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSNull_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

**EDIT:**

Based on screenshots in comments:
If you using this category to your Dictionary from SBJSON this is very wrong. You assume that everything you received from JSON is `NSString` which is not true. If you don't and using it for every sub-dictionaty this is ok.

Change

```
if(object == nul)
```

to

```
if([object isKindOfClass:[NSNull class]])
```

or in your JSON (this is really REALLY wrong!)

```
if([object isKindOfClass:[NSString class]])
   if([(NSString*)object isEqualToString:@"<null>"])
```

And please edit your original post with code. Not pase a screenshots in comments.

Comment: I use code like link here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12213822/replace-occurance-of-nsnull-in-nested-nsdictionary --> but value null don't replace, and i have no idea

Comment: Which part of code? where? I can help you if you don't post your code and sample JSON.

Comment: Sample Json -> http://mocku.ps/wz69f, and my code is ->http://mocku.ps/m41e1h

Comment: I've edit my original answer.

Comment: I've used to dispatch_asycn to get json from to service, and it has value null string, exactly i see the string is <null> when i put nslog.In my question i'm going to write code to clear, but when the json code it breaks font should I put on the visual image, thank you for your words comments

Answer (score 0):

you can do this by using `enumerateKeysAndObjectsUsingBlock:`. Here is the solution you are trying, check this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8477789/iterating-through-nsdictionary-for-null-value#answer-8478820).

Comment: thank @arthan.v, i have seen link, the code doesn't work, and i still not yet replace all the value null in json